# pageContainer change is not getting fired at all

Tags: jquery-mobile

As `changePage` is deprecated in jQuery mobile, I am using `pageContainer` as follows

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pageContainer("change", "springboard.html", {});
```

and even this

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer("change", "springboard.html", {});
```

but none of the above are working , i am firing this above method on a button click.

[jquery mobile pageContainer issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502029/jquery-mobile-pagecontainer-issues)

[pagecontainer change function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912099/pagecontainer-change-function-not-working)

i have checked other threads too but no luck

Comment: `.pageContainer.pagecontainer` lowercase "c" in second "container".  The second function is correct and should fire.

Comment: make sure that event is called on button click. Pls post more click handler code.

Comment: it is getting called , and i am using jquery 1.9 is that fine ?

Comment: sure it's fine. with jqm 1.4 use at least jquery 1.9